# How to remove ubuntu and install windows 10 on Thinkbook 15 G2 ITL

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, windows-10

I have Lenovo Thinkbook 15 G2 ITL 20VE00FTTX and I am trying to remove ubuntu and install windows 10 instead. I made a windows 10 bootable USB using windows tool on a different windows pc. The problem here is I can't boot from the USB as when I press F12 the USB name does not appear there and even when I opened the bios and disabled secure boot it didn't work.

I added down all the settings that I have in the bios (configuration - security - boot ) so that it would be easier to tell me how to boot from the USB to install windows 10 on the SSD hard.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ViqXr92bI0-rlbSl52u-mfmjhpsGP8yh?usp=sharing

I noticed that ubuntu sys is installed on the HDD hard and the sdd hard doesn't appear even in the bios.

I've watched many videos but I couldn't find any similar options to what I have now in the boot settings.

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: the OS installed is not of importance when installing another OS so this is not about Ubuntu.

Comment: You can ask this question in superuser.com instead.